# Can Glimpse.MVC5 be used with an MVC6 project?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, glimpse

I'm converting an ASP.Net MVC5 project to ASP.Net 5 with MVC6.
The original project had Glimpse.MVC5 installed and I see that there is no NuGet package for MVC6.

1. Can Glimpse.MVC5 be used with MVC6?
2. If Yes, can I just install the NuGet package or should I do a Manual installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Glimpse for MVC5 does not support the new AspNet <del>5</del> Core MVC (6).

Instead, install Glimpse version `2.0.0-beta1`, which does support the new framework. (Though it is not yet feature complete.)

The [full installation instructions are available on the Glimpse blog](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2015/11/19/installing-glimpse-v2-beta1/).